# Haskell: Changing an element at a given index in a ByteString

Tags: haskell, bytestring, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm trying to change a character at indices x and y in a matrix made of `ByteString`s to a different character. Initially, I used `[[Char]]` to represent the matrix, so I was able to use `.~` from `Control.Lens.Setter` to change the value, but this doesn't seem to work for `[ByteString]`.

Is there any way to use the lens or to modify the element without `unpack`ing the `ByteString` like I'm doing right now?

The code, right now, is:

```
render :: [[Char]] -> [Loc Int] -> [[Char]]
render maze []               = maze
render maze (Loc (x,y):locs) = render mutate locs
    where mutate = element y . element x .~ '*' $ maze
```

Where `Loc` is just:

```
newtype Loc a = Loc (a,a) deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for ByteStrings:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Lens

-- change character at position 2 to a space (ASCII code 32)

test = (BS.pack "abcdef") & ix 2 .~ 32
```

Note that ByteStrings are really containers of Word8 values, so that's we need to use the ASCII code here.

The `ix` operator works for a lot of other data structures like Text, lists, Sets, Maps, etc -- see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#t:Ixed) for more details.

Comment: You can avoid the 32 by using `fromEnum ' '` or (with `Data.Char`) `ord ' '`.

Comment: That is, `fromIntegral . fromEnum`, which really should have a name.